# Sorting Object Array in Symfony on the basis of date & time

Tags: symfony

//Suppose Entity Notes has property 'creationdate' & 'getCreationDate()' method to access.

```
  DefaultController extends Controller {
         public function indexAction(){
           $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           $repository = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Notes');
           $notes = $repository->findBy(array('userid' => $userId);
           //Now I want to sort the notes array as per creation date using usort
           usort($notes, array($this,"cmp"));
        }
     function cmp($a, $b) {
       return strtotime($a->getCreationDate()) > strtotime($b->getCreationDate())? -1:1;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the order in your call to the repository rather than after like so...

```
$notes = $repository->findBy(
    array('userid' => $userId),    // search criteria
    array('creationdate' => 'ASC') // order criteria
);
```

I know you said you wanted to use usort but it seems kind of unnecessary.

Comment: but if I want to search the basis of on date and time at which note is created, it shows sorted but for notes created on same date it shows in descending order.. :( is there any solution Thanks in advance..

Comment: It would depend on how you want them sorted but you can just add to the sorting (the second) array. If, for example, you wanted to order by title you would use `array('creationdate' => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC')`